# Rapid App Prototyping Tools for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, expression-blend, rapid-prototyping

Expression Blend + SketchFlow provides a template for Windows Phone rapid application prototyping which is very useful specifically when one is going to share the app design and mockup functionalities with customer in early stages. The template provides very similar UI elements such as pivot and panoramic controls just like real controls provided by SDK.

I wonder if there exist templates for Android and iOS platforms which mimic exact UI elements in each platform.
Does anyone know where I may find?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about JustInMind? They just launched a new [free version of Prototyper](http://www.justinmind.com/prototyper/free-edition).

Answer (score 5):

I'm developer of [MockingBot](https://mockingbot.com/), we recently launched a new version with brand new design, i think you should give it a try.

[image: MockingBot snapshop]

Answer (score 2):

Here's another you may want to try: http://www.fluidui.com/

Comment: i m using it now, and it is perfect! really good..